# comparing value of two list python django?

Tags: python, django

I have a two list coming from my views and I am comparing them and checking the values which match on a multi select drop-down. But the logic seems to work fine but it tends to multiply the data coming in multi select.

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label text_left">University <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select class="form-control" value="university_all_list.id" name="universityId"
                id="universityName" required>
            <option>Select</option>

            {% for university_name in university_all_list %}
                {% for id in university_ids_list %}
                {% if  id == university_name.id %}
                    <option value="{{ university_name.id }}"
                            selected>{{ university_name.name }}</option>
                {% else %}
                    <option value="{{ university_name.id }}">{{ university_name.name }}</option>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any solution for this that it doesn't multiply my data in drop-down. I know I am using multiple for loop it is because of that,but what could be the solution for that.

my views:

```
@login_required
@csrf_exempt
@cms_user_edit_decorator
def admin_user_edit(request, cms_user_id=None):
    university_ids_list = []
    university_ids ={}
    university_all_list = Universities.objects.using('cms').all()
    master_cms_user_type_list = MasterCmsUserTypes.objects.all()
    cms_user = CmsUser.objects.get(userId=cms_user_id)
    school_university_mapping = SchoolAdminUniversityMappings.objects.filter(userId=cms_user)
    for university_ids in school_university_mapping:
        university_ids_list.append(university_ids.universityId)
    print university_ids_list
   # zip_list = zip(A, cycle(B)) if len(A) > len(B) else zip(cycle(A), B)
    user_obj = {}
    user_showing = 'edit'
    if cms_user_id is not None:
        user_showing = 'edit'
        user_obj = User.objects.get(id=cms_user_id)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            first_name = request.POST.get('firstName').strip()
            last_name = request.POST.get('lastName').strip()
            username = request.POST.get('username').strip()
            email = request.POST.get('email').strip()
            status = request.POST.get('status')
            university = request.POST.getlist('universityId')
            print 'hulu lulu'
            print university
            staff = False
            superUser = False
            if status is None or status == '':
                status = False
            else:
                status = True
            if user_obj.email == email:
                if user_obj.username == username:
                    if cms_user_id:
                        user_obj = User.objects.get(id=cms_user_id)
                        user_obj.first_name = first_name
                        user_obj.last_name = last_name
                        user_obj.email = email
                        user_obj.username = username
                        user_obj.is_active = status
                        user_obj.is_staff = staff
                        user_obj.is_superuser = superUser
                        user_obj.save()
                        messages.success(request, 'Successfully update to the Admin User')
                        return redirect('cms:admin-user-list')
                else:
                    if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                        messages.error(request, 'username already registered')
                    elif cms_user_id:
                        user_obj = User.objects.get(id=cms_user_id)
                        user_obj.first_name = first_name
                        user_obj.last_name = last_name
                        user_obj.email = email
                        user_obj.username = username
                        user_obj.is_active = status
                        user_obj.is_staff = staff
                        user_obj.is_superuser = superUser
                        user_obj.save()
                        messages.success(request, 'Successfully update to the Admin User')
                        return redirect('cms:admin-user-list')
            else:
                if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    messages.error(request, 'email already exists')
                elif cms_user_id:
                    user_obj = User.objects.get(id=cms_user_id)
                    user_obj.first_name = first_name
                    user_obj.last_name = last_name
                    user_obj.email = email
                    user_obj.username = username
                    user_obj.is_active = status
                    user_obj.is_staff = staff
                    user_obj.is_superuser = superUser
                    user_obj.save()
                    messages.success(request, 'Successfully update to the Admin User')
                    return redirect('cms:admin-user-list')
    return render(request, 'templates/admin_user_management/admin_user_edit.html', {
        'user_obj': user_obj,
        'user_showing': user_showing, 'master_cms_user_type_list': master_cms_user_type_list,
        'cms_user': cms_user,'university_all_list':university_all_list,'university_ids_list':university_ids_list,'list':list
    })
```

Comment: could you post the view also?

Comment: what is getting multiplied?

Comment: the value of this university_all_list is getting multiplied in drop down

Comment: `the logic seems to work` It works or it doesn't work. There is no such a thing likw `seems to work`

Comment: sir the main logic was to select the value after comparing them and show check mark on the selected item from dropdown but on the other hand it multiplied the dropdown values.like for example i have 400 results in my drop down and ion my second loop if the value is 3 then i have 1200 values in my drop down

Comment: I think you'are overcomplicating the things. Please read the Zen of Python: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/ and after that reconsider how can you refactor the whole code. A view function with more than a dozen lines is nothing bad a bad designed code.